# Avoid R terminal printing typed characters while performing a task

Tags: r, terminal, readline

I'm using vanilla R on Linux, and when R is computing something and I press keyboard buttons, they get printed to the terminal.

For example, if I type "foo" while R is sleeping, the following happens:

```
Sys.sleep(1) #Typing "foo" now before the sleep ends...
foo>foo      #"foo" is both registered and shown before the sleep ends
```

This of course may be wanted in some cases, but there are cases in which I'd like the terminal to be as clean as possible. In this case both the following options would be good:

1. Ignore any keypress that is registered before the completion of the previous command;
2. Do not ignore keypresses, but simply do not show them before the completion of the previous command.

To clarify, this is what should happen in those two cases if you write "foo" while R is sleeping:

1:

```
Sys.sleep(1) #Typing "foo" now before the sleep ends...
>            #Nothing is registered
```

2:

```
Sys.sleep(1) #Typing "foo" now before the sleep ends...
>foo         #"foo" is registered but not shown before the sleep ends
```

Is there any way I can accomplish one of the two?